# Как получить jwt токен

Tags: android, oauth, jwt

В приложении можно авторизоваться через google .
После автаризации в kakaotalk, клиент получает токен и другие параметры:
И казалось бы все хорошо, но тут же следующем запросом идет авторизация на сервер приложения, в котором передается JWT токен (X-Access-Token).

Насколько я знаю токен подписывается секретным ключом и поэтому его нельзя сuенерировать на клиенте, но запросов для генерации jwt на сервер не было, тогда как генерируется токен?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю секретный ключ на то и секретный чтобы его нельзя было получить. Посему я думаю у вас есть два выхода:

1. Найти решение без генерации jwt токена - допускаю что у вас где-то проблема в взаимодействии с сервером. Не могли люди пишущие данный сервис не предусмотреть работу клиента в их системе. Клиент никогда не занимается генерацией ключей доступа к серверу, это не его задача и архитектурно серверу придется заранее знать секретный ключ чтобы сверять то что вы закодировали и то что он должен ожидать. Вот пример декодирования токена:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[вот инструмент](https://jwt.io/) для такого. Чтобы получить информацию например из jwt токена (то что находится в правой стороне таблички на скрине) можно использовать такой вариант:

```
private fun decodeToken(jwt: String): String {
        val parts = jwt.split(".")
        return try {
            val charset = charset("UTF-8")
            val payload = String(Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(parts[1].toByteArray(charset)), charset)
            payload
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            "Error parsing JWT: $e"
        }
    }
```

и дальше использование метода:

```
val mDecode = decodeToken(строка_с_вашим_токеном)
val sid = JSONObject(mDecode).getString(название_поля_нужного_вам)
```

но так вы секретную часть как вы понимаете не получите :(

2. Ну и второй вариант решения проблемы - связаться с разработчиками сервиса (если вы не делаете ничего противозаконного) и спросить у них апи для работы или документацию.

Я бы вам советовал изучить как именно происходит авторизация, где берется токен, может там какие-то запросы раньше проходят. Я очень сильно сомневаюсь что вам нужно генерировать токен, либо придется где-то найти ключ для его создания.